# How to get text value from <span> inside <div> with pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="auc col-100 mgb-1">
  <span class="xtag" id="test1"><span>test1</span><a href="#" class="tagDel">x</a></span>
  <span class="xtag" id="test2"><span>test2</span><a href="#" class="tagDel">x</a></span>
</div>
```

How can I get `test1` and `test2`?

```
xtag.forEach(function(){
    var s = [];
    s.push(document.querySelector('.xtag span').innerText.toLowerCase())
});
```

I want to check to

```
s.indexOf(valcheck)
```

If use jQuery I can use `find()`, but vanilla JavaScript still makes me confused.

Comment: where is `xtag` is defined

Comment: In your `forEach` callback, you can use the first argument to refer to your elements in your array. Then you probably can use children.innerText to get your values

Comment: thanks for comment, i got the answer already by @Mamun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [**Document.querySelectorAll()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var s = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.xtag span'));
s = s.map(el => el.innerText.toLowerCase());
console.log(s); // ["test1", "test2"]
console.log(s.indexOf('test1')); // 0
console.log(s.indexOf('test2')); // 1
```

```html
<div class="auc col-100 mgb-1">
  <span class="xtag" id="test1"><span>test1</span><a href="#" class="tagDel">x</a></span>
  <span class="xtag" id="test2"><span>test2</span><a href="#" class="tagDel">x</a></span>
</div>
```